Big Query :Calculate customer journey on Monthly bases
I have order table in that column named membership paid and paid date (Created At column) need to show the customer journey like he/she paid membership fees payment on monthly basis.On cycle order
enter image description here
cusotmerid   Joindate   January (Cycle 1)           Feburary(Cycle 2)        March (Cycle 3)
Customer123 2024-12-01      1st membershipfees             Missed         2nd membership fees
Suppose if they missed one payment it should displayed missed payment and remaining should be counted1,2,3 (Ranking order)
